# Ajax send data using POST method, but PHP function does not INSERT them to the table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I have a problem with receiving data from AJAX using the POST method.

At first, everything worked properly, but then something happened and now I can't find the bug.
If I check my AJAX everything dispatched properly, but PHP does not receive the data. As a result, it does not insert data into the database table.

My jQuery:

```js
$('#button-send-review').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var th = $(this);
    var name = $("#name_review").val();
    var good = $("#good_review").val();
    var bad = $("#bad_review").val();
    var comment = $("#comment_review").val();
    var iid = $("#button-send-review").attr("iid");
    var add_review = $("#button-send-review").val();

    if (name != "") {
        var name_review = '1';
        $("#name_review").css("borderColor", "#DBDBDB");
    } else {
        var name_review = '0';
        $("#name_review").css("border", "2px solid #d20000");
    }

    if (good != "") {
        var good_review = '1';
        $("#good_review").css("borderColor", "#DBDBDB");
    } else {
        var good_review = '0';
        $("#good_review").css("border", "2px solid #d20000");
    }

    if (bad != "") {
        var bad_review = '1';
        $("#bad_review").css("borderColor", "#DBDBDB");
    } else {
        var bad_review = '0';
        $("#bad_review").css("border", "2px solid #d20000");
    }

    if (name_review == '1' && good_review == '1' && bad_review == '1') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./",
            data: "goods_id=" + iid + "&name=" + name + "&good=" + good + "&bad=" + bad + "&comment=" + comment + "&add_review=" + add_review,
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
        }).done(function() {
            $(".success").addClass("visible");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
                $(".success").removeClass("visible");
                $.magnificPopup.close();
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
});
```

My Controller:

```php
<?php
if ($_POST['add_review']) {
    add_review();
}
?>
```

My Model:

```
<?php
function add_review() {
    global $link;

    $goods_id = trim($_POST['goods_id']);
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $good = trim($_POST['good']);
    $bad = trim($_POST['bad']);
    $comment = trim($_POST['comment']);

    $goods_id = clear($goods_id);
    $name = clear($name);
    $good = clear($good);
    $bad = clear($bad);
    $comment = clear($comment);

    $query = "INSERT INTO reviews(goods_id, name, good_reviews, bad_reviews, comment, date)
              VALUES($goods_id, '$name', '$good', '$bad', '$comment', NOW())";
    $res = mysqli_query($link, $query) or trigger_error($link->error . "[DB]");

    return true;
}
?>
```

My HTML:

```html
<div id="send-review" class="popup-form">
    <div class="success">Thank you! <br>
        Your review send for moderation.
    </div>
    <h4 id="title-review">The review would be posted soon.</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label id="label-name"><span>Name *</span></label>
            <input maxlength="15" type="text" id="name_review" placeholder="Enter your name..." style="border-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label id="label-good"><span>Pros *</span></label>
            <textarea id="good_review" placeholder="Enter pros..." style="border-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label id="label-bad"><span>Cons *</span></label>
            <textarea id="bad_review" placeholder="Enter cons..." style="border-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label id="label-comment">Comment</label>
            <textarea id="comment_review" placeholder="Your comment..."></textarea>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="button-wrap">
        <button class="button" type="submit" id="button-send-review" name="add_review" value="Send" iid="92">Send</button>
    </div>
    <button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">&times;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what errors do you have?

Comment: what was that " something happened"?

Comment: First of you need to learn prepare statements the way your SQL is created it vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. Secondly do you get any errors in the console.

Comment: can you echo test in this condition if ($_POST['add_review']) { echo "test";} and tell me what you get?

Comment: you are returning only true from the php and your ajax isn't appending that on the page

Comment: I don't have any errors, just nothing happens. After fillind my review form, I have succes div with "Thank you. Your review send to moderation". But I don't see the new review because it doesn't appear in mysql table. On the network tab I see all the data that were sent, but I cant understend where they were sent.

Comment: How can I check this statement if ($_POST['add_review']) { echo "test";} . When I put it to controller after filling the form I see just how AJAX works, after pushing send button I return to the page and don't see ant echo...

Comment: Something happens means that It worked properly and now it doesn't work

Comment: @LevelLevel chack my code in answer

Answer (score 0):

Your $.ajax() data isn't formatted correctly;

Should be like this example to receive the POST strings in your receiver page:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
});
```

And please use prepared SQL statements to secure against SQL Injections.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried, but unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: Are you also sending something with POST add_review? - $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { add_review: "yes", goods_id: "and your", name: "other fields" }
});

Answer (score 0):

The posting format in the ajax method is incorrect;

change ajax code to :

```
<script>
$('#button-send-review').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var th = $(this);
    var name = $("#name_review").val();
    var good = $("#good_review").val();
    var bad = $("#bad_review").val();
    var comment = $("#comment_review").val();
    var iid = $("#button-send-review").attr("iid");
    var add_review = $("#button-send-review").val();

    if (name != "")
    {
        var name_review = '1';
        $("#name_review").css("borderColor", "#DBDBDB");
    } else {
        var name_review = '0';
        $("#name_review").css("border", "2px solid #d20000");
    }

    if (good != "")
    {
        var good_review = '1';
        $("#good_review").css("borderColor", "#DBDBDB");
    } else {
        var good_review = '0';
        $("#good_review").css("border", "2px solid #d20000");
    }

    if (bad != "")
    {
        var bad_review = '1';
        $("#bad_review").css("borderColor", "#DBDBDB");
    } else {
        var bad_review = '0';
        $("#bad_review").css("border", "2px solid #d20000");
    }



    if (name_review == '1' && good_review == '1' && bad_review == '1')
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./",
            data: {"goods_id":iid,"name":name,"good":good,"bad":bad, "comment":comment,"add_review":add_review},
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
        }).done(function () {
            $(".success").addClass("visible");
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
                $(".success").removeClass("visible");
                $.magnificPopup.close();
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to stop SQl Injection

Comment: goods_id:92
name:d
good:d
bad:d
comment:
add_review: Send; I see data in Network tab, but I don't understend what happens after this. I think that if($_POST['add_review]) does't receive the  data

Comment: @LevelLevel data can not be received?

Comment: I think so. After using $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] in controlled I have GET, printed on the webpage. I think maybe the reason in this...

Comment: There may be an error in your controller or in your frameworks structure.Have you checked the inputs at the controller calling?

Comment: How can i check the controller inputs? For example when i print $_POST i get and ARRAY, but when I print $_POST['add_review'] I get nothing

Comment: for check input data use : var_export($_POST[]);die;

Comment: Gives answer: array ( )

Comment: @LevelLevel Do you implement the code yourself or use the framework?

Comment: Check your code for redirect.
This causes post data to be erased

Comment: You mean redirect in .htacces? I removed .htaccess from the root directory and nothing changed...How can I check redirects in another way? Thank you...I think that this problem appeared when I transferred webside from http to https, but despite on this I checked everything on localhost with http protocol...And problen still the same

Comment: Press f12 to check correct in your firefox browser. Before sending the form. Go to network tab. Click the button to submit.
Check the type of posting and the parameters sent from network tab.
You will find in this section whether the information was sent to the page you were looking at or sent to another page.

Comment: I've done this step in the very beginning, everything was correct, data are being sent, but function doesn't put them to sql table